# Login Page takes me to Homepage Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, authentication, dashboard

Every time I try to login to my WordPress like this: https://excelinsbrokerage.com/wp-admin/
it says: "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page."

So then I try with: https://excelinsbrokerage.com/wp-login.php and I am able to put my user and password but it takes me to the homepage no matter what.

So far I have tried:

1. Deactivate the plugins one by one (renaming the plugin folder)
2. Renaming the whole plugin folder: wp-content/plugins2
3. Deleting .htaccess file
4. Deactive the Theme folder (rename the theme folder)
5. Resetting the permalink settings thru Database (on the wp-options table)
6. Changing the current theme to twentynineteen theme thru the Database
7. Changing the current permalinks settings thru the Database

Also I have tried modifiying my .htaccess with the following values just in case it helps but it does not work:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any other idea of what can I try to avoid this to be able to login to the dashboard I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the default admin user or one created by yourself? It could be a matter of permissions.

The wordpress says you can't access or it is a browser error?

Comment: that's the user I have always used. It's nothing about permissions. Or Folder permissions neither.

Answer (score 0):

I am so happy to post this with my own answer. For those who come here with the same issue and did not find a solution yet.

This is what was causing the issue on the login: A hacked Database or Database with Malware code on the tables.

Here is how i found the issue and how I solved it:

I download the Database of my website and open the .sql file on my Sublime Editor. First I found that there were a lot of tables with strange names like: wp_n68bjx6chf_usermeta or wp_n68bjx6chf_options or even wp_n68bjx6chf_users aside from the common tables: wp_usermeta, wp_options, wp_users (check the screenshots)

So, first thing is to identify the tables with similar names and get rid of them. Leave only the original tables.

[image: name on tables]

Also i found that the Wordfence tables had no legible code on the insert into queries, I don't what they mean but this is for sure a malware code or hacked code on the Db.

So I decided to GET RID OF THE WORDFENCE TABLES and the INSERT INTO queries that were inserting those malicious code on the tables. See the screenshot.

[image: wordfence tables]
[image: wordfence tables]

At last but not least, I found that some values on the wp_options were modified as well. That's why, among the rest of the things, i were not able to login to the Db.

Like for example this value on the wp_options table:

[image: wp_options table]

wp_user_roles this is very important but the value inside was: wp_19dzt1jzj3_user_roles which of course is not the correct value that's why the login did not recognized my user as administrator and did not let me login or show me the dashboard with all the pages and post, options.

So i modified that value on the wp_options to wp_user_roles.

I saved my new version of DB and then import it on my server. And it worked! Hopefully it works for anybody